# Eclipse: Program "/xlC" not found in PATH

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse Mars `4.5.1` CDT on Linux shows this message in **Problems** tab while build is successful:

```
Program "/xlC" not found in PATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet [suggested](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/369309/) disabling  "CDT XLC Error Parser" which is named as "xlC Error Parser" in Mars.1:

Window->Preferences->C/C++->Build->Settings->Error Parsers->xlC Error Parser

[image]